# How to read a text File in Rust and read mutliple Values per line

Tags: rust

So basically, I have a text file with the following syntax:

```
String int    
String int  
String int
```

I have an idea how to read the Values if there is only one entry per line, but if there are multiple, I do not know how to do it.

In Java, I would do something simple with while and Scanner but in Rust I have no clue.

I am fairly new to Rust so please help me.

Thanks for your help in advance

***Solution***
Here is my modified Solution of @netwave 's code:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Error};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let buff_reader = BufReader::new(fs::File::open(file)?);
    for line in buff_reader.lines() {
        let parsed = sscanf::scanf!(line?, "{} {}", String, i32);
        println!("{:?}\n", parsed);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Smells like Advent of code :)

Comment: @Netwave yes youre right :)

Comment: See [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Read) and the `read_to_string` function, good to read the whole file, or you could use `BuffReader` in Netwave's answer to read one line at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`BuffRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#) trait, which has a [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) method. Also you can use [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines).

For doing so the easiest option would be to wrap the `File` instance with a [`BuffReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html):

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
...
let buff_reader = BufReader::new(fs::File::open(path)?);
loop {
    let mut buff = String::new();
    buff_reader.read_line(&mut buff)?;
    println!("{}", buff);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3Aprelude%3A%3A*%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3ABufReader%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Afs%3A%3AFile%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20-%3E%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3AResult%3C()%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20f%20%3D%20File%3A%3Aopen(%22log.txt%22)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20reader%20%3D%20BufReader%3A%3Anew(f)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20line%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20len%20%3D%20reader.read_line(%26mut%20line)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22First%20line%20is%20%7B%7D%20bytes%20long%22%2C%20len)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%7D&edition=2018)

Once you have each line you can easily use [`sscanf`](https://docs.rs/sscanf/latest/sscanf/) crate to parse the line to the types you need:

```rust
let parsed = sscanf::scanf!(buff, "{} {}", String, i32);
```

Comment: If you would rather write your own macro to parse the data instead of using a crate, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d83afa7e844ec2da8daae7a955d9af9) is a low-tech version that is still pretty versatile. (playground doesn't support IO, so I just gave it a literal, but it shows its usage still)

Comment: thanks for this simple piece of code, I slightly modified it

Answer (score 0):

Based on: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/file/read_lines.html

For `data.txt` to contain:

```
str1 100
str2 200
str3 300
```

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // File hosts must exist in current path before this produces output
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines("./data.txt") {
        // Consumes the iterator, returns an (Optional) String
        for line in lines {
            if let Ok(data) = line {
                let values: Vec<&str> = data.split(' ').collect();
                match values.len() {
                  2 => {
                    let strdata = values[0].parse::<String>();
                    let intdata =  values[1].parse::<i32>();
                    println!("Got: {:?} {:?}", strdata, intdata);
                  },
                  _ => panic!("Invalid input line {}", data),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

// The output is wrapped in a Result to allow matching on errors
// Returns an Iterator to the Reader of the lines of the file.
fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

Outputs:

```
Got: Ok("str1") Ok(100)
Got: Ok("str2") Ok(200)
Got: Ok("str3") Ok(300)
```

Comment: A little bit overcomplicated, but a valid answer

Comment: good point! not beginner friendly, playground link from Netwave is good and simple!

Comment: Yeah, his answer got shortened using things like the try operator (`?`), killing the need for `if let`s and `sscanf` seems good enough to do the parsing job.